# Python 3: Store the contents of a file into one big string

Tags: python, string, text, input, python-3.x

Suppose I have a textfile with this content:

> Hello World My name is Sam
>
> I am 12 years old and a boy
>
> I like Pizza

And I wanted to store it into one big string, no newlines, no spaces or anything so it would read like this:

> HelloWorldMynameisSamIam12yearsoldandaboyIlikePizza

How would I do that? Google hasn't been much help.

Comment: Do you want to keep or throw away characters like quotes, commas, etc?

Comment: Throw away, but the file I am using doesn't have them, so I don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex, eg:

```
import re

with open('input') as fin:
    long_string = re.sub(r'\W', '', fin.read())
# HelloWorldMynameisSamIam12yearsoldandaboyIlikePizza
```

Note that `\W` is equiv. to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` so you could change it to `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` if you wanted to be explicit about anything that's a non ascii letter/digit.

Comment: You will end up throwing away all of the punctuation with the whitespace.

Comment: @BryanOakley yup, but 1) there's not any, and 2) "no newlines, no spaces or *anything*" - emphasis mine - is open to a bit of interpretation - there's enough info. here hopefully for the OP to adapt for desired characters.

Comment: That's what I needed.  I'm not worried about punctuation, there isn't in the files I'm using. I just need all the characters to be one big string.  Thank you!